# How to make a button mouse over highlight a text area

Tags: c#, forms

I'm working on a app where I think it would be helpful that when a mouse hovers over the button that essentially will copy data to a clipboard from multiple fields it displays that to the user by changing the TextBox background/border.

```
[enter name             ]          [Copy Button]
[enter date             ]
```

When mouse is over [Copy Button] both name and date boxes change color.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this sounds very doable ..what have you even tried on your own.. you should do some research first you can google how to copy text to ClipBoard in C# then google the mouse move and or hover etc....

Comment: This is definitely a fairly simple problem... Give it a shot and post what you wrote, explaining what isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used standard form to test with 3 textboxes, and 1 button.

see code --

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText("Box 1: " + textBox1.Text + "\r\nBox 2: " + textBox2.Text + "\r\nBox 3: " +textBox3.Text);
        }

        private void highlightbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            textBox2.BackColor = Color.LightGray;  
        }

        private void unhighlightbox(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.Empty;
            textBox2.BackColor = Color.Empty;
        }

    }
}
```

Then I went to the button1 in the design screen clicked it once so i could edit its properties in the properties window, selected the events button at the top of that window, and assigned the MouseEnter to highlightbox and MouseLeave to unhighlightbox.

Works for what i want it to do. changing. on to the next question after some research.

Sorry for the easy question. here's a solution since maybe someone else will have a similar problem locating it.